# no contacts with Rockmite

Tags: antenna, diy, qrp

I finished building my [Rockmite ][](http://www.qrpme.com/?p=product&id=RM4). It's running off of 3x 18650s, or 12v. I connected it to a [MFJ-1840T](http://www.mfjenterprises.com/Product.php?productid=MFJ-1840T) and held the antenna horizontally in the air (also tried vertically) with my hand. I tried calling [clean](https://hamprojects.info/Mortty/) CQ on 7.030 mHz and get no response. I tried with and without a counterpoise attached to the MFJ. My [nanoVNA](https://m.alibaba.com/product/62342877955/Hugen-NanoVNA-H-New-item-Original.html) tells me the antenna has an SWR of ~2. I tried seeing my signal on a websdr 100 miles away to no avail. I'm in a suburb.

I have lots of questions. I also don't know which of the following are necessary or not, or where to start.

- because I'm holding the antenna, should I be expecting nvis contacts only?
- is my hand wrapped around the antenna base heat shrink hurting things? What's the better way?
- how sensitive is my setup to time of day?
- would building a G5RV instead of the MFJ be the thing to get me some contacts? Thus focusing on the antenna instead of more watts.
- would investing in a QRP SDR such as the [RS-HFIQ](https://www.hobbypcb.com/index.php/products/hf-radio/rs-hfiq) make it possible to chase down band activity and move to more active frequencies to make a contact? Would this help me deduce receiver capability of my antenna setup?
- are newer digital modes other than cw required to be successful in QRP?
- should I join a club and being my setup to others to help me figure it all out with?
- should I climb a mountain peak and try the same thing again?
- do I need to figure out how to get the swr down?
- I type for 2-5 minutes before giving up. How long would it take to get a typical bite (response)?
- do I just need more watts? Am I attempting the rare or impossible? Is the rockmite just not usable in this part of the solar cycle without an amplifier?
- is there something else I'm not thinking of that is making it impossible for me to make a contact?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see what your problem is.

[That's a 1.4 meter long, based-loaded, telescoping, end-fed vertical antenna](http://www.mfjenterprises.com/Product.php?productid=MFJ-1840T). 
It has *significant* losses on 40 meters.

Furthermore, all end-fed antennas require a good RF return, such as a resonant elevated radial or counterpoise. Since you don't mention that, that indicates to me that very little of your signal is actually being radiated.

A full-size, center-fed, 40 meter dipole cut for 7.03 MHz is a little bit more than 67 feet long, and no counterpoise is required. I can almost guarantee you that you'll get some answers with one of those!

**I strongly discourage using a G5RV** for the reasons listed [on the G3TXQ page about them](http://www.karinya.net/g3txq/g5rv/).

Comment: Thank you! You have now confused me though on the difference between a counterpoise and a radial. Is it a radial when the wire is touching the ground?

Comment: @mh00h Well, the difference is actually subject to a lot of debate. But one thing is for certain: one elevated radial is going to be *far* more effective than one radial lying on the earth.

Comment: @Mh00h For the purpose of this Question, "counterpoise" and "radial" are synonyms.  Close enough, anyhow :-)

Comment: I wanted to report back that using a full size center fed dipole indeed fixed the issue. Thank you! I can hear all sorts of activity with it! I nobody hears me because my little .5W rockmite doesn't have enough power. Thanks again.